# how to Get Angle of diagram

Tags: triangles, angle

[image: Diagram Image]

What is $\angle{CAD}$ ?

What i tried

[image: What i've tried]

using all angle properties opposite side of angle etc but i guess my angle $\angle{CAD}$ is wrong

Comment: $60+20+110 \neq 180$. The $60$ degree angle should instead be...

Comment: There are some nice solutions here: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/IndexToClassical.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Your only error is in the leftmost triangle, which your diagram says has angles of $110°$, $60°$, and $20°$. Solving from start to finish, you'll see that the $60°$ angle should instead be $\color{red}{50°}$.